# How to use wine on Raspbian

Tags: windows, emulation

I used a Kali Linux with wine which was pre installed in it. I found that wine is already in the repo of buster. I installed it . And I used an exe file to run.(it was the 8086 emulator. File name is td.exe).

It said >> bad exe file(or something like that)

My qestion is how to use wine software properly on Raspbian?
How to configure everything? 
I found a lot of tutorials with exagear but I couldn't find it in the repo. How to run an exe file with wine?

Answer (score 2):

You (mostly) can't, despite the availability.

WINE is not a real/conventional emulator (hence the recursive acronym, "Wine Is Not an Emulator").  It translates Windows API<sup>1</sup> calls into POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface), with which Raspbian and GNU/Linux generally are compatible.

However, it is starting from already compiled machine code.  Machine code is compiled for specific processor categories.  Windows applications mostly only come in 32 or 64 bit x86 flavours, which includes most laptops and desktops but not the Raspberry Pi.<sup>2</sup>

So, while WINE itself will run, the executable format of the stuff it might be used with will not.

Note that [this page from WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM) is suggestive, but, besides looking abandoned, should be tempered [by this page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Emulation).  I'm guessing if you compile stuff for Windows on the platform (eg., Windows IoT) you could run that stuff.  It does **not** mean you can run x86 executables in WINE on ARM.

---

1. Maybe ABI makes more sense there, although understanding the difference is not important.
2. Windows for phones and such means there are ARM executables, but that will probably not help you with WINE.  Stuff for Windows IoT, which runs on the Pi, may be feasible.

Comment: with Box86/Box64 it is possible to run x86 programs on ARM CPUs: https://box86.org/