# WINE ARM64 install for Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit to run Windows for ARM native applications

Tags: software-installation, windows, emulation, wine

I have used WINE with Ubuntu Linux on x86 Intel CPUs to run Windows applications compiled for x86. I now want to use WINE ARM64 with Raspberry Pi OS 64 to run Windows for ARM applications compiled for ARM64.

How can I download and install a recent version of WINE ARM64 for Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit to run Windows for ARM applications compiled for ARM64?

The environment I want to use:

- Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit with WINE ARM64 to run applications
- Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition on a Windows PC to create the application targeting ARM64 rather than x86

I have used Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to create a sample ARM64 application that I then ran on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Windows for ARM and that worked fine.

There is an ARM install available in Raspberry Pi Software installer tool however the version is 5.x and the current WINE version appears to be 8.x as of August 2023. And I'm not sure whether what is installed is actually ARM 64 bit version of WINE or not. I'm also unsure if it installs just WINE or does it install some kind of x86 emulator that I don't want or need as well.

This Raspberry Pi SO article isn't helpful: [How to use wine on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105208/how-to-use-wine-on-raspbian) for what I need.

This information, [WINE HQ - ARM64](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM64) doesn't appear to have been updated since 2018.

I've found the following resources however they seem to require Box86 or similar emulator.

[Raspberry Tips - Get Started with Wine on Raspberry Pi (Beginner’s guide)](https://raspberrytips.com/install-wine-raspberry-pi/)

[Performance topic: Running x86 games on Raspberry PI OS 32 bits (Box86/Wine/PiKISS)](https://thepigamer.blogspot.com/2021/01/performance-topic-running-x86-games-on.html)

**Other questions**

Can I use any software that targets Debian ARM64 with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit? My understanding is that Raspberry Pi OS is based on Debian Linux. Would a version of WINE for Debian ARM64 work with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit?

Should I pick a different operating system to use, replacing Raspberry Pi OS 64 with something else such as Ubuntu? How well does that work?

**Notes**

1. It looks like the WINE ARM64 package for Debian is located at [Package: wine64 (5.0.3-3)](https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/wine64/download). However at [Download Page for wine64_8.0.1~repack-3_arm64.deb on 64-bit ARMv8 machines](https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/wine64/download) there is the most recent version. There is also a note that says:

> You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` like this:
>
> `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main`
> Replacing `ftp.de.debian.org/debian` with the mirror in question.
>
> One such mirror is `ftp.us.debian.org/debian`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a preliminary process for building an ARM64 Windows application and then running the application using WINE on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit. I do not fully understand what I have managed to do so further experimentation is needed.

My development environment on a PC:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2019 with the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension and the ARM64 toolkit enabled

My running environment on the Raspberry Pi 4:

- Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit
- WINE 8.0.1 installed using `apt-get` after modifying my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

**First attempts**

I created a new Windows Desktop C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. This created a barebones Windows Desktop application with a main window sporting a menu bar with a few bare necessities such as a `File` menu and a `Help` menu.

I changed the Configuration from the default of `x86` to `ARM64`. The result was an exe file for an ARM 64 bit processor. I then used the open source NSIS Installer packaging software to create an installer .exe.

In order to use NSIS, I downloaded the installer for the Visual Studio C++ runtime for ARM64 as I assumed it would be needed by the application. The runtime was included in the NSIS installer file. The runtime is available from [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

I installed WINE using the Raspberry Pi Add/Update Software utility which installed WINE 5.0.3.

I tried installing my Windows Desktop application with WINE and the install failed. Thinking that perhaps it was a problem with the NSIS installer even though it should be compatible with ARM64, I added the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension to Visual Studio 2019 to generate an .msi file type of installer.

After creating an installer project and adding it to my Visual Studio 2019 solution and setting up the basic settings after watching a couple of YouTube videos on the subject, I was able to generate an .msi file type of installer. Using the extension, I could just select an option to include the runtime and let the Visual Studio extension find it.

Using WINE 5.0.3 with this new .msi installer also failed with an error.

**What worked**

I removed WINE 5.0.3 from my Raspberry Pi 4. I next installed WINE 8.0.1 for ARM64 using the instructions at this page, https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/wine64/download which contained more recent Debian ARM64 version of WINE.

I then tried to install my Windows Desktop application once again with WINE. This attempt was successful however the procedure and what I saw displayed on the screen was a bit confusing. However in the end I did have my Windows Desktop application installed in my Downloads folder where I had put the installer and which was my working directory when I did the install with WINE.

WINE 8.0.1 appears to display a window that appears to be a kind of miniature Windows Desktop GUI showing various folders and allowing you to navigate about within the WINE folder hierarchy. I was able to navigate using the GUI to where my Windows Desktop application was installed and to then double click the application file to start it up.

When the application displayed its main window, I was able to manipulate the menus and pop up the Help about dialog.

**Final thoughts**

1. It appears that the version 5.0.3 of WINE which is what the Raspberry Pi Add/Update software utility shows has some problems. WINE 8.0.1 works much better.
2. I can build a simple Windows Desktop application with Visual Studio 2019 using an ARM64 configuration and I can run it on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS 64 using WINE 8,.0.1.
3. I do not know if the NSIS installer version will work with WINE 8.0.1 or not and that will require further experimentation.
4. I do not know what level of complexity a Windows Desktop application must reach before it will not run. Can I use COM objects and other software components? What parts of the Windows API is not available with WINE 8.0.1?
5. I need a better understanding of what WINE is doing when it installs an application. With that understanding, I can make the changes to my installer to better cooperate with WINE. For instance, the folder hierarchy that WINE created was strange. The top most folder, the folder created in my Downloads directory was named `'Default Company Name'` and the folder created in that folder was `installer`. These names came from somewhere in the .msi installer however I don't yet know where.
6. Lastly, it appears that modifying my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file caused `apt-get` to see versions of libraries and components that the latest and possibly unstable. I commented out the additional software mirror that I added to the file as I wanted a reasonably healthy and functioning Raspberry Pi OS. I need to better understand the ramifications of adding the additional mirror in order to access WINE 8.0.1.